# Cannot run ionic angular app in browser using the ionic serve command

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic6, ng

I am trying to run my first ionic angular app in a browser to see if I had installed ionic 6 properly on my computer. But I get this error message when using the ionic serve command. I included a reference link to the article that I am following: [Running the Ionic app](https://ionic-5-full-starter-app-docs.ionicthemes.com/running-the-app).

> ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
> [ng] Error: Unknown arguments: host, port
>
> [ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).
>
> The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.

I am hoping to see some message that tells me that my test angular app is running with the ionic 6 framework. Sorry, I'm new to this so my question might sound confusing. I would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you follow the tutorial that you referenced from the begenning, but in the [previous step "set up the development environment"](https://ionic-5-full-starter-app-docs.ionicthemes.com/set-up), it's mentionned to install ionic with :

```bash
npm install -g ionic
```

But for Ionic starting version 6 and after, this is not the same package.
Check in the official documentation ["How to install the Ionic CLI"](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v6/intro/cli#install-the-ionic-cli).

So you have to run :

```bash
npm uninstall -g ionic
npm install -g @ionic/cli
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I got it good for now!

Comment: can you please accept my answer if it helps you ? thank you

Comment: Just accepted! Sorry about that, but I really appreciate your answer. Thank you.